# Matplotlib hexbin log scale colorbar tick labels as exponents

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

When creating a 2-d histogram with matplotlibs [`hexbin`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) with log scale colours (`bins="log"`), the colorbar shows exponents instead of values:

[image: hexbin plot with log scale colours]

How can I make it show values and exponent tick marks as in the x and y axes in the plot above?

Answer (score 6):

A partial answer is to use `norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()` instead of `bins='log'`. This doesn't show the lesser tick marks though

[image]